# How to get values in hidden fields without clicking the submit button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I am using jQuery to set some values in hidden fields, which are being set perfectly.

But the problem is hidden fields don't show me the values until I submit the form.

Is there away to get at the values before the form is submitted.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#hdnCountryCode").val(geoip_country_code());
$("#hdnCountyName").val(geoip_country_name());
$("#hdnCity").val(geoip_city());
$("#hdnRegionCode").val(geoip_region());
$("#hdnRegion").val(geoip_region_name());
$("#hdnLatitude").val(geoip_latitude());
$("#hdnLongitude").val(geoip_longitude());
});
</script>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnCountryCode"  />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnCountyName" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnCity" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnRegionCode" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnRegion" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnLatitude" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnLongitude" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnV" Text="s" onclick="btnV_Click"  />
<%
Google.Values Send = new Google.Values();
Send.CountryName = hdnCountyName.Value;
Send.CountryCode = hdnCountryCode.Value;
Send.RegionName = hdnRegion.Value;
Send.RegionCode = hdnRegionCode.Value;
Send.City = hdnCity.Value;
Send.Latitude = hdnLatitude.Value;
Send.Longitude = hdnLongitude.Value;
%>
</form>
</body>
```

With the code above the values of the hidden fields when passing to the properties of my class is giving me "". But when I use button click event same code returns me all the values which i need

Comment: If you want to retrieve the value in code, you can use `$("#hdnCountryCode").val()` (pass no parameter to `.val()` and it returns the current value). Is that what you mean? Or are you trying to ask about how to debug your code?

Comment: You need to use AJAX for this. In the `$(document).ready()` after populating the fields, add AJAX request that will send those values to the server then you can use them in your server side C# code.

Comment: ShadowWizard can u give me some explanation for doing the things u just said please

Comment: You need to ensure that ASP.Net renders the correct ID, as you have it the client ID will be prefixed with additional values, use the ClientIDMode="Static" property to render the ID you specify <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnCountryCode" ClientIDMode="Static" />

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you need to get the rendered id, and this is done like:

```
$("#<%=hdnCountryCode.ClientID%>").val(geoip_country_code());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this code:

```html
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var countryCode = geoip_country_code();
            var countryName = geoip_country_name();
            $('#countryCode').html(countryCode);
            $('#countryName').html(countryName);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        CountryCode: <span id="countryCode">countryCode</span>
    <p>
    <p>
        CountyName: <span id="countryName">CountyName</span>
    <p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to explain what your code does and how it differs from the code in the question.

Comment: without any explanation, it's difficult to find the use in answers like this.